# $_POST array is empty after submitting the from

Tags: php, html, post, forms, http-post

I have a simple form (below), I want to send the Name field in email but POST is empty.

HTML Form:

```
<form action="contact.php" method="post">
   <div class="form-group">
     <label for="name">Name:</label>
     <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name">
   </div>
   <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
</form>
```

PHP:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['name'])){
    $to = "example@example.com";
    $subject = "Test subject";
    $txt = $_POST['name'];
    $txt .= "test txt";
    $headers = "From: example2@example2.com" . "\r\n" .
    "CC: somebodyelse@example.com";
    if (mail($to,$subject,$txt,$headers)){
        echo "succes";
    }else{
        echo "failed";
    }
} else {
    echo "Name is required!";
}
?>
```

Does anyone has an idea what could be wrong? I have other forms on this server and they are working fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Input has to have a `name` attribute.

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name">
```

Comment: Oh god.... Yes this was solved my problem thank you
I was copied it from a bootstrap example there was no name attribute.

Comment: @celodir Confirm if this is the right answer then.